# Lista simplemente enlazada C

Tags: c, lista, manejo-de-memoria, imprimir

lei varios temas de estos pero no logro entender mi problema, estoy tratando de hacer una lista simplemente enlazada y no entiendo por que me sale el error segment fault (las ultimas veces es cuando no aloque memoria para lo que necesitaba hacer).

Problablemente estoy entendiendo mal la logica de como funciona la estructura, me confundo un poco con mis estructuras.

Las estructuras que estoy utilizando son las siguientes, esto seria mi header ("lista.h"):

```
struct Nodo
{
  int dato;
  struct Nodo *sig;
};

typedef struct{
  int n;
  struct Nodo *lista;
}Lista_T;

Lista_T Crear_Lista();

void Insertar_Primero(Lista_T *l, int x);

void Recorrer_lista(Lista_T l);
```

Luego mis funciones las defino de la siguiente forma:

```
#include "lista.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

Lista_T Crear_Lista( )
{
  Lista_T l;
  l.lista= NULL;
  l.n = 0;
  return l;
}


int Esta_vacia(Lista_T l)
{
  return (l.n == 0);
}


void Insertar_Primero(Lista_T *l, int x)
{
  struct Nodo *nuevo = NULL;

  if ((nuevo = (struct Nodo*)malloc(sizeof(struct Nodo))) == NULL)
  {
    printf("No se puede alocar memoria");
    exit(-1);
  }
  
  nuevo -> dato = x; //actualizar los punteros
  nuevo -> sig = l->lista;

  l->lista = nuevo; //llevo a la cabeza de la lista al comienzo de nuevo
  l->n++; //actualizo tamaño
  

}


void Recorrer_lista(Lista_T l)
{

  if (!Esta_vacia(l))
  {
   struct Nodo *p= l.lista;
        while(p != NULL){
            printf("%d ", p->dato);
            p= p->sig;
        }
    }   
    else
        printf("Lista Vacia.");
  
  
}
```

Simplemente hice las funciones para crear una lista, verificar si esta vacia, insertar un nuevo nodo al inicio de la lista y recorrer la lista para verificar si todo esta ocurriendo según creo, sin embargo estoy obteniendo segmentation fault.

Las estoy utilizando en el main.c asi:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "lista.h"

int main()
{
  Lista_T lista;
  int dato;
  
  Crear_Lista(&lista);
  Insertar_Primero(&lista, 12);
  Insertar_Primero(&lista, 15);
  Insertar_Primero(&lista, 20);
  Recorrer_lista(lista);
  
  return(0);
}
```

Tengo varias inquietudes, en prinicipio sospechaba de recorrer_lista ya que no aloque memoria para el punto *p que recorreria la lista imprimiendo los datos ya que si hago esto no tengo el error de segmentation fault pero imprime solamente un 0, les escribo como cambiaria la funcion Recorrer_lista

```
void Recorrer_lista(Lista_T l)
{

  if (!Esta_vacia(l))
  {
   struct Nodo *p = l.lista;
   p = malloc(sizeof(struct Nodo));
   
        while(p != NULL){
            printf("%d ", p->dato);
            p= p->sig;
        }
    }   
    else
        printf("Lista Vacia.");
  
  
}
```

De esa forma me devuelve un 0 y por algun motivo que no comprendo si en lugar de alocar p hago una alocacion en p->sig imprime "20 0", o sea solo imprime el ultimo valor agregado y un 0

por si no se entiende tambien poco ese codigo:

```
void Recorrer_lista(Lista_T l)
{

  if (!Esta_vacia(l))
  {
   struct Nodo *p = l.lista;
   p->sig = malloc(sizeof(struct Nodo));
   
        while(p != NULL){
            printf("%d ", p->dato);
            p= p->sig;
        }
    }   
    else
        printf("Lista Vacia.");
  
  
}
```

En estos momentos estoy sospechando si estaré haciendo bien la inserción del dato cuando uso "Insertar_Primero" ya que tendria sentido que solamente se aloque el segundo y el resto se borren ya que me di cuenta que nunca hago un free() para la alocacion del vector del dato nuevo. Sin embargo al hacer el free solamente tengo como resultado 0 y con eso me dejo medio perdido.

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu `main` tienes:

```
Crear_Lista(&lista);
```

La función `Crear_Lista` está definida así:

```
Lista_T Crear_Lista( )
{
  Lista_T l;
  l.lista= NULL;
  l.n = 0;
  return l;
}
```

donde ya encontramos dos errores.

El primero es que la función no usa la lista que se le entregó. En lugar se eso crea una variable local `l` y la retorna. Ese es el segundo error: la variable es local y desaparece tan pronto haces el `return`.

Entonces, cuando haces

```
Insertar_Primero(&lista, 12);
```

intentas agregar un valor a una lista que nunca fue inicializada.

Hay una cantidad de errores e inconsistencias en las declaraciones. Para corregirlas considera que estas operando con punteros, y todos las funciones deben estar declaradas con punteros.

En lugar de

```
int Esta_vacia(Lista_T l)
{
  return (l.n == 0);
}
```

debes declarar

```
int Esta_vacia(Lista_T* l)
{
  return (l->n == 0);
}
```

y en lugar de usar `l.n` debes usar `l->n`

Comment: Efectivamente el problema estaba en el main que le estaba mandando &lista cuando en realidad tenia que escribir lista = Crear_Lista();